# What's the main purpose of update()? Why can't my code work without update()?

Tags: python, for-loop, random, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

The code slowly generates columns of randomly selected numbers 1 and 0 on a 1920x1080 canvas

```
def matrix():
    c.configure(bg="black")
    numbers=[0,1]
    for i in range(100):
        for j in range(50):
            c.create_text(i*20,j*20,text=random.choice(numbers),fill="green")
            c.after(50)
            c.update() # <code>\<</code>------
matrix()
```

What's the main purpose of `update()`? Why can't my code work without `update()`?

I've had a look around but couldn't really understand. You could say I'm stupid.

Comment: you should clarify which programming language you are using and fix your formatting.

Comment: @anarcat Tkinter is a Python module, so Python

Comment: @SneakyTurtle sure but you'll have more answers if you tag your question properly. and you still need to fix the formatting. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code *does* work without calling `update`. It's just that you can't see it working because you don't let tkinter refresh the window.

In order for tkinter (or any GUI toolkit) to function, it must be able to respond to a steady stream of events. Things like button clicks, typing, resizing a window, or drawing to a canvas, all cause events to be added to a queue.

Normally these events are processed by the event loop, which is what `mainloop` is. It is a loop that simply waits for events to arrive, and then it handles them.

Because tkinter is single-threaded, it can only do one thing at a time. Thus, as long as your code is doing something (eg: your `for` loop), it is unable to process events. If it can't process events, any changes to the UI (such as drawing on the canvas) won't be visible.

When you call `update`, you are requesting that tkinter process all pending events that are stuck in the event queue. Note that this processes *all* events in the queue, so if you clicked in a button, that click will get processed too. This can result in a deeply nested set of calls to `update` if each time you call, it processes an event that causes it to be called again.

Since what you want is not to process all events, but rather just events related to refreshing the display, you can instead call `update_idletasks` which only processes "idle" events. "idle" events are events that tkitner processes when it is otherwise idle. One such event is the request to refresh the display.